# Ceasar cipher in c wrong output

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I need to shift the letters of a given string based on a base string (i.e. the alphabet) and an integer.
The goal of the function is to remain within the base string.
Exemple:

```
string to shift: a b c
key: -6
output: u v w
```

But instead I get:

```
output: [ \ ]
```

Which means that the shift is done based on the ascii table instead of the base string.
I'm having a hard time figuring out why? :(

Here's the code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void    cesar(char *str, int shift);

int     main(void)
{
    char    str[1001] = "ikio kyz rg ykiutjk vgmk ja robxk";
    char    temp[1001];

    strcpy(temp, str);

    printf("%s\n", str);
    cesar(temp, -6);
    return (0);
}

void    cesar(char *str, int shift)
{
    char    alphabet[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char    c;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            c = alphabet[i] + (str[i] - alphabet[i] + shift);
            str[i] = c;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

output:

```
ceci est la seconde page d[ li\re
```

instead of:

```
ceci est la seconde page du livre
```

Thx ^^

Comment: When you say `c = str[i] - str[i];` you know you could just write `c=0` yeah?

Comment: Indeed , that was in the heat of the moment...

Comment: `alphabet` seems pretty unused...

Comment: @4386427 I know, I have it there as a reference... I'm trying to figure out how to use it?

Comment: consider when `i==0, str[0]==a`. Then `c==0, c==-6, -6 % 26 == -6`. `str[0] = -6 + 'a'` --> `-6 + 97 == 91 == '['`. You're not wrapping around to the end of `alphabet` (not using it at all as mentioned).

Comment: @yano, I did some edits to the code... I get the same output...

Comment: SO isn't meant to be an open-ended running debug session. But consider the same scenario, `i==0, str[0]=='a'`. `alphabet[i] + (str[i] - alphabet[i] + shift)` --> `'a' + ('a' - 'a' - 6)` --> `'a' - 6 == '['`, Of course you got the same output... _Think_ about the case where the shift takes you `< 'a'`, you need to wrap around back to `'z'`.

Comment: @yano, Thx a bunch ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to implement the shift without any incorrect values

```
    if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
    {
        c = str[i] - 'a'; // 0 <= c < 26
        c += shift;       // any value possible (no limits on `shift`)
        while( c < 0 ) c += 26; // no longer negative
        while( c > 25 ) c -= 26; // no longer 26+
        str[i] = c + 'a';
    }
```

Subtracting the value of `a` translates from an ASCII constant to a letter index (0...25) which can be manipulated by the cipher code. Adding `a` at the end translates back to ASCII.

What your code was doing was blindly adding the shift to the letter, after doing the %26 check. This means that letters that went before the start of the alphabet, and needed to be wrapped past the end of the alphabet ('u' and 'v' in your test case) were not corrected.

Comment: @TimRandell, thx a bunch.

Comment: "c += shift;       // any value possible (no limits on `shift`)" is amiss as `c` is a `char`.  Consider `'z' + 6`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't know what you're getting at with the "Consider". My comment is meant to indicate that we can no longer assume that `c` is within particular limits. After addition of a value that could be any `int` (because there are no limits imposed on the value of `shift`), `c` could hold any possible value — within the constraints of its definition as a `char`, obviously.

Comment: My particular concern is in error.  I was considering `c + shift` as if `c` had the value of `z` and not 25 as in your code.  OTOH `c + shift` can overflow with large `shift` resulting in UB.  A precaution would reduce `shift` with `shift %= 26;` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Form the offset from `'a'`**

**Modulo vs remainder**

`%` is the remainder, not the Euclidean modulo.

```
 // Offset from `a`
 int c = (str[i] - 'a') + shift;

 // modulo
 c %= 26; // c now in range -25 to 25
 // Handle negative values 
 if (c < 26) c += 26;

 // Undo the offset  
 str[i] = c + 'a';
```

---

Tip: perform a one time `shift %= 26;` before the loop to prevent overflow possibilites with `(str[i] - 'a') + shift` when `shift` is near `INT_MAX`.
Use `int c`, not `char c`, again, to prevent overflow.